# Am I using &lt; correctly?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I am new to HTML and Xpath and need a little help.

I am trying to use the less than function in HTML but it keeps coming up with an error.

`value.singleNodeValue.setAttribute("select", "match[round &lT; '"+matchround+"']");`

where `round` is an attribute name and `matchround` is the user input I want to compare to.

Can someone please highlight what I am doing wrong as the greater than statement works perfectly.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I dont get and output at all this is my code for both greater than and less than if (searchcondition1=="GreaterThan") {
            // greater than
            value.singleNodeValue.setAttribute("select", "match[round > '"+matchround+"']");
        } else {
            // Less than
            value.singleNodeValue.setAttribute("select", "match(round  &lt; '"+matchround+"'");

Comment: You need to explain and show the context of your question, you say "I am trying to use the less than function in HTML" but HTML does not have functions at all. And less than in XPath is an operator, not a function. Is the code you have shown Javascript? Are you trying to set an attribute value to an XPath expression? That does not make sense in the context of HTML as HTML attributes don't have XPath expressions as their value. How does the XPath expression you want to construct look like exactly? In XPath itself the operators `<` and `>` are never escaped.

Comment: Have you tried just a normal `<`.  I don't know this for a fact, but it's possible that you only need to encode when using XPath *within* XSLT, and that you should just the normal '<' outside of XSLT.  As I say, this is purely a guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General and parameter entities in XML are **case sensitive**.

`&lT;` (with a capital `T` as is currently shown in the code in your question) is not the same as `&lt;`.

It's also not real clear how your example is intending to use XPath.  It looks like you're just trying to set an attribute named `select` with a string that has barely a passing resemblance of the XPath `match()` function.  Note also that `match()` is only available in XPath 2.0.

The answer to your asked question is that you must use `&lt;` (case sensitive) instead of a literal `<` in XML so that parsers do not mistake the `<` for the start of an element.

The answer to your real question will depend on your [clarification of what your true end goal is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I have tried it with in lower-case still no difference

Comment: @FarhadAli Why let people guess what might be wrong? Just show _all of your code_, and the input, and remove tags that do not apply (you are not using XSLT I guess).

Answer (score 0):

What kind of comparison do you want to make, what kind of value does `matchround` have? Is it a string or a number? XPath 1.0 does not support less than or greater than comparisons on string values, only number comparison. And you say that `round` is an attribute name, in that in XPath you need `@round`. So if `matchround` is a number (e.g. 50) then doing `setAttribute("select", "match[@round < " + matchround + "]")` would create an attribute with the XPath expression `match[@round < 50]` as its value. Any escaping would happen only if the DOM tree is serialized, the attribute value in the DOM would contain the pure XPath expression with a `<` character, not with an entity reference.